# Sorting last item to oldest item using Fetch Core Data

Tags: swiftui

I would like to sort the last value to the oldest in my favorite view using core data timestamp. I found multiple answers and tried pretty much most of them. Unfortunately, they do not work for me. Can someone please help and guide me on my code below? My entity "Favorite" has the attribute "timestamp" of type Date. Thanks in advance.

```
import Foundation
import CoreData

class CoreDataFavoriteManager {
    
    private let container: NSPersistentContainer
    @Published var savedFavoriteEntities: [Favorite] = []
    
    init() {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "FavoritesContainer")
        container.loadPersistentStores { _, error in
            if let error = error {
                print("Error loading Core Data! (\(error)")
            }
        }
        
        fetchLyrics()
    }
    
    // MARK: PRIVATE
    private func fetchLyrics() {
        let request = NSFetchRequest<Favorite>(entityName: "Favorite")
        let sort = NSSortDescriptor(key: "timestamp", ascending: false)
        request.sortDescriptors = [sort]
        
        do {
            savedFavoriteEntities = try container.viewContext.fetch(request)
        } catch let error {
            print("Error fetching FavoriteEntity! \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    //Update time to CoreData
    private func updateTime() {
        let newTime = Favorite(context: container.viewContext)
        newTime.timestamp = .now
    }
    
    // Save to CoreData
    private func save() {
        do {
            try container.viewContext.save()
        } catch let error {
            print("Error saving to Core Data! \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    private func delete(entity: Favorite) {
        container.viewContext.delete(entity)
        applyChanges()
    }
    
    private func applyChanges() {
        updateTime()
        save()
        fetchLyrics()
    }
    
    
    private func addFavorite(song: TuunoLabu, onTappedButton: Bool) {
        let newFavorite = Favorite(context: container.viewContext)
        newFavorite.id = Int32(song.id)
        newFavorite.isFavoriteSong = onTappedButton
        newFavorite.timestamp = Date()

        applyChanges()
    }
    
    private func updateFavoriteSong(entity: Favorite, onTappedButton: Bool) {
        entity.isFavoriteSong = onTappedButton
        entity.timestamp = Date()
        applyChanges()
    }
    
    // Updating:
    func updateFavorite(song: TuunoLabu, onTappedButton: Bool) {
        if let entity = savedFavoriteEntities.first(where: { $0.id == song.id }) {
            if onTappedButton {
                updateFavoriteSong(entity: entity, onTappedButton: onTappedButton)
            } else {
                delete(entity: entity)
            }
        } else {
            addFavorite(song: song, onTappedButton: onTappedButton)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is how I subscribe and publish my favorite.

```
import Foundation
import SwiftUI
import Combine

class TapToggle: ObservableObject {
        
    @Published var allSongs: [TuunoLabu] = []
    @Published var savedNotes: [TuunoLabu] = []
    @Published var savedFavorites: [TuunoLabu] = []
    
    private let fetchingJsonFile = FetchingJSONFile()
    private let coreDataNoteManager = CoreDataNoteManager()
    private let coreDataFavoriteManager = CoreDataFavoriteManager()
    private var cancellables = Set<AnyCancellable>()

    
    init() {
        subscribeFetchingJSONFile()
        fetchNoteCoreData()
        
    }
    
    
    private func subscribeFetchingJSONFile() {
        fetchingJsonFile.$allSongs
            .sink { [weak self] (receivedData) in
                self?.allSongs = receivedData
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)
    }
    
    
    private func fetchNoteCoreData() {
        // Note Mapping
        $allSongs
            .combineLatest(coreDataNoteManager.$savedNoteEntities)
            .map { (lyrics, noteEntites) -> [TuunoLabu] in
                lyrics
                    .compactMap { (notedSong) -> TuunoLabu? in
                        guard let entity = noteEntites.first(where: { $0.id == notedSong.id }) else {
                            return nil
                        }
                        return notedSong.updateNotes(note: entity.notes ?? "")
                    }
            }
            .sink { [weak self] (receivedEntities) in
//                DispatchQueue.main.async {
//                    self?.savedNotes = receivedEntities
//                }
                self?.savedNotes = receivedEntities
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)

        // FavoriteMapping
        $allSongs
            .combineLatest(coreDataFavoriteManager.$savedFavoriteEntities)
            .map { (lyrics, favoriteEntities) -> [TuunoLabu] in
                lyrics
                    .compactMap { (favoriteSong) -> TuunoLabu? in
                        guard let entity = favoriteEntities.first(where: { $0.id == favoriteSong.id }) else {
                            return nil
                        }
                        return favoriteSong.updateFavorite(favorited: entity.isFavoriteSong)
                        
                    }
            }
            .sink { [weak self] (receivedEntities) in
                self?.savedFavorites = receivedEntities
            }
            .store(in: &cancellables)

    
    
    func updateNote(song: TuunoLabu, text: String) {
        coreDataNoteManager.updateNote(song: song, text: text)
    }

    func updateFavorite(song: TuunoLabu, onTappedButton: Bool) {
        coreDataFavoriteManager.updateFavorite(song: song, onTappedButton: onTappedButton)
    }
}
```

Here is my Favorite View when I favorite one of the songs.

```
struct FavoriteView: View {
    
    @EnvironmentObject var tap: TapToggle
    @State private var selectedNameIndex = 0
    @State private var selectedTab: Int = 0
    @State private var closedSheet: Bool = false
    
    let sortedHymnNames = ["Newest", "Num(Asc)", "Num(Dec)", "A-Z", "Z-A"]
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            //Color.theme.menuColor.ignoresSafeArea()
            RadialGradient(colors: [Color.theme.menuColor, Color.theme.menuColor2], center: .leading, startRadius: 10, endRadius: 400)
                .ignoresSafeArea()
            
            VStack(spacing: 0) {
                
                sortingView
                    .padding(.vertical, 8.0)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 3.0)
                
                favoritePBPListingView
            }
        }
    }
    
    private func sortingTypes() -> [TuunoLabu] {
        switch selectedNameIndex {
        case 0:
            return tap.savedFavorites // This is the default sorting and should be in Newest to Oldest
        case 1:
            return tap.savedFavorites.sorted(by: { $0.id < $1.id })
        case 2:
            return tap.savedFavorites.sorted(by: { $0.id > $1.id })
        case 3:
            return tap.savedFavorites.sorted(by: { $0.zoTitle < $1.zoTitle})
        case 4:
            return tap.savedFavorites.sorted(by: { $0.zoTitle > $1.zoTitle })
        
            
        default:
            return tap.savedFavorites
        }
    }
}

// Extension:
extension FavoriteView {
    private var sortingView: some View {
        
        VStack (spacing: 12) {
            HStack {
                Image(systemName: "person")
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .opacity(0)
                
                Spacer()
                
                Text ("Favorites")
                    .font(.title3)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                    .foregroundColor(.secondary)
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                
                Spacer()
                
                HomeButtonView()
                    .padding(.horizontal)
                    .padding(.vertical, 8)
            }
            
            HStack {
                ForEach(0..<5) { num in
                    
                    Button(action: {
                        
                        selectedNameIndex = num
                        
                    }, label: {
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Text(sortedHymnNames[num])
                            .font(.system(size: 11, weight: .bold))
                            .foregroundColor(selectedNameIndex == num ? .primary : Color.theme.tabTextColor)
                            .padding(.horizontal, 5)
                            .padding(.vertical, 5)
                            .background(
                                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 7)
                                        .strokeBorder(Color.indigo, lineWidth: 2)
                                        .opacity(selectedNameIndex == num ? 0.5 : 0)
                            )
                        
                        Spacer()
                    })
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `savedFavoriteEntities` contains?

Comment: Are you looking to sort the output when grabbing all items from the database - i.e. the database can return data in any order but the data visible to the user should be sorted by timestamp? If so, the easiest way might be to use a sort descriptor that is tied to the @FetchRequest. Could you show the code for the view where this data is being retrieved and displayed?

Comment: Thanks for the quick replies. These problems have been bugging me for awhile. I will update the rest of the code. I hope there are not too much code in my question. Again, thank you.

Comment: Updated the question. I apologize ahead for the messy codes.

Comment: @AlejandroL.Rocha, the `savedFavoriteEntities` contains all the updates of favorites I have made. I passed it down to `TapToggle` to do Combine framework.

Comment: Here the `Note Mapping` is exactly the same as `Favorite Mapping`. I can update both as soon as I can figure out the `Favorite` part.

Comment: Hi @nickreps, do you have any update?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could point out where the data that needs to be sorted is displayed. My assumption is that you need the data inside the ForEach(0..<5) { num in ... etc to be sorted - is this correct?

Comment: Yes. As you can see, `0` is the default sorting. If my Core Data was correct, then it will automatically sorted as Newest to Oldest that I have already favorited based on the Core Data timestamp. Now the default ForEach(0) is sorted as the JSON id which is basically the same thing as ForEach(1).